# What are these numbers under tabs in Guitar Pro?

Tags: guitar, notation, sheet-music, tablature, guitar-pro

I know that piano sheets sometimes has something similar and suggests you which fingers to use to play the note or chord. But... this is guitar, and looking into these numbers I don't believe these are finger numbers. It just looks weird: 4 & 1 for three finger chord? Also, check the last number in highlighted area: 4 is gone?

[image]

Also, what setting in Guitar Pro 6 should I use to hide these numbers?

Comment: Can't you hold two strings with one finger if two notes are on the same "row"?

Comment: Sure. It's called *barre*. But I can't make a chord that is spanned across three frets with a single finger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks indeed like the finger indication.
But Guitar Pro doesn't do that automatically, so it's the author of the tab that chose these numbers, which might explain why they're strange.

It doesn't seem that there is an option in the Stylesheet (F7 shortcut) to remove them.
You can change their position (in the "Notation" tab - left-hand fingering), but I don't see anything to hide them, so you'll have to remove them from the tab "manually", one by one.
Yeah, that sucks.

To remove them, select the note and on the left panel, click on the "left hand" icon (on the same row as hammer-on / pull-off buttons) and click on the circled number.

But you're right, it should not be displayed like it is on your tab.
With the finger notation you rarely indicate all fingers you use, only the more relevant / unusual ones. So, with the options set up like yours, it's unusable. With the right set of options ("standard" notation displayed, position on staff before the note), it's much more readable as the number is next to the relevant note.
It looks like an after though from Arobas, poorly implemented, with options missing (you can't even change the font). I'll send them a little feedback :).

Answer (score 0):

You can select "file", "export" then select "Midi".  Then open that newly saved midi file.  All the fingering is gone. If the song contains a Capo, you need to remove it before saving as a Midi file but have it keep the fingering, this is done under Tuning.